# how to use lapply for concat.split()

Tags: r, split, lapply

How do you use `lapply` to split columns into multiple columns with the same delimiter ",".
From columns 12 to 14 of a data frame I am working with, there are multiple strings of words and I want to split within each of the columns with the delimiter ",".

So, some rows between `c(12:14)` have up to two to four commas delimiter. Therefore, I do not know how many new columns will be created from the concat.split.

I am trying to use `concat.split` to get the job done.

Here is the code I have used and it's not working.

```
library(splitstackshape)

concatsplit<-function(x){concat.split(.,"x",",")}

dataframe_concat<- lapply(dataframe[c(12:14)], concatsplit)
```

Thank you in advance for the guidance!

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: What version of splitstackshape are you using? You should be able to just do something like `cSplit(dataframe, 12:14, ",")`.

Answer (score 0):

This answer does not answer the question "how to use lapply". However it does the job if you are willing to use another package than the `splitstackshape`

You can use the functions from stringr to find the maximum number of occurences of your separator with `str_count`. You can then use this count to tell `separate` how many additional columns you will have.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df <- tibble(a = c("a,b,c", "A,b", "A,B,C,C,D,E"),
             b = 1:3)
```

```
#not run
#> df
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  a               b
#  <chr>       <int>
#1 a,b,c           1
#2 A,b             2
#3 A,B,C,C,D,E     3
```

```
df %>% 
  separate(a,
           into = paste0("a_",
                            as.character(1:(max(str_count(df$a, ","))+1))),
           sep = ",")
```

```
# output:
## A tibble: 3 x 7
#  a_1   a_2   a_3   a_4   a_5   a_6       b
#  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <int>
#1 a     b     c     NA    NA    NA        1
#2 A     b     NA    NA    NA    NA        2
#3 A     B     C     C     D     E         3
```

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't address their question at all. I think they're just not aware that splitstackshape can be used to split multiple columns at once.